# broadleaf demo site tomcat persistence unit exception

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-data, broadleaf-commerce

I am trying to get my hands dirty on broadleaf, was trying to run broadleaf demosite on tomcat. For this purpose i addes db related props in catalina.properties, but i am facing below errors.

```
[ WARN] 03:30:43 RuntimeEnvironmentPropertiesConfigurer - Unable to determine runtime environment, using default environment 'development'
[ WARN] 03:30:47 MergePersistenceUnitManager - A BroadleafClassTransformer is configured for this persistence unit, but Spring reported a problem (likely that a LoadTimeWeaver is not registered). As a result, the Broadleaf Commerce ClassTransformer (org.broadleafcommerce.common.extensibility.jpa.copy.DirectCopyClassTransformer) is not being registered with the persistence unit.
[ WARN] 03:30:50 AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [org.hibernate.cache.spi.UpdateTimestampsCache]; using defaults.
[ WARN] 03:30:51 AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory - HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [blSandBoxElements]; using defaults.
[ERROR] 03:30:52 ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in resource loaded from byte array: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: blPU] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1488)
   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1117)
   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:922)
   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
   at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
   at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
   at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
   at org.broadleafcommerce.common.web.extensibility.MergeContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(MergeContextLoaderListener.java:50)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
   at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
   at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
   at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

As per my initial investigation it seems to be a load time weaving problem due to which ehcache shuts down and the above mentioned exceptions results.

Complete log with debug mode on can be seen at https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=EA49CD7184E0E40!169&authkey=!AP_Pe0s0Va7U1S8&ithint=file%2c.out

Comment: The log file that you posted does not contain any stack traces, no way to really tell. I would imagine there are more details in the stack trace that you posted above.

Comment: @phillipuniverse somehow tomcat problem is solved but i am getting another problem of " StaticAssetViewController - Unable to retrieve static asset" log can be seen at
https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=EA49CD7184E0E40!170&authkey=!AP34FlOtpDUH5EQ&ithint=file%2c.out

Comment: @phillipuniverse is there any place where i can get documentation of blc thymeleaf tags like blc:bundle, blc:categories, etc